# How to display the message in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I tried to display the message in django admin by using print method, but do not display the message.

Can you help me to display the message in Django admin by using condition?

Comment: `print` will display the message in console or stdout. Try using [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/)

Answer (score 0):

Show messages in django

```
messages.debug(request, '%s SQL statements were executed.' % count)
messages.info(request, 'Three credits remain in your account.')
messages.success(request, 'Profile details updated.')
messages.warning(request, 'Your account expires in three days.')
messages.error(request, 'Document deleted.')
```

You need to study [django message](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/) docs